# Are eigenfunctions always normalizable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue

If $y$ is an eigenfunction which corresponds to the eigenvalue $a$ of the operator $A$:

$$A\langle y|=a\langle y|$$

Can we assume that $$\int y^*y=1$$ ?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. Please complete your question.

Comment: Usually we normalize eigen-functions to avoid expressions like $\langle A\rangle=\langle|\psi|A|\psi\rangle/\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$. We normalize functions and $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$ becomes unity. If you do not normalize function, you should keep in mind mentioned expression in observables calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: eigenfunctions of the momentum operator $\hat{p} \sim - i\frac{\partial} {\partial x} $ are not normalisable over non compact spaces such as $\mathbb{R}^d$. The solutions are plane waves that can be normalised in a distributional sense:
$$\int d^d x\, y_p(x)^\star y_{p'}(x) = \delta^d( p - p'). $$

Comment: I'd like to add to this that in for any *matrix*, all eigenvectors *are* normalizable.